# update data in table based on data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 table1
-----------------------------
| id (int) |  dt (datetime) |
-----------------------------
|    1     |  12-12-2012    |
|    2     |  13-11-2013    |
|    3     |  23-07-2014    |
|    4     |  13-06-2014    |
-----------------------------


 table2
-----------------------------
| id (int) | dt2 (datetime) |
-----------------------------
|    1     |  12-12-2012    |
|    1     |  13-11-2013    | -> update table1 id=1 with this dt2
|    2     |  23-07-2014    |
|    2     |  13-06-2014    |
|    2     |  12-12-2012    | -> update table1 id=2 with this dt2
|    3     |  13-11-2013    | -> update table1 id=3 with this dt2
|    3     |  23-07-2014    |
|    3     |  13-06-2014    |
|    4     |  23-07-2014    |
|    4     |  13-02-2014    | -> update table1 id=4 with this dt2
-----------------------------
```

I want to update `table1.dt` with the corresponding `dt2` from `table2` based on the `id`.

However, I do not want to update `table1.dt` to the largest corresponding  datetime value from `table2.dt2`.

I only want to update `dt` to the largest corresponding `dt2` which is not greater than the current date.

So far what I have gotten is:

```
update table1
set table1.dt = table2.dt2
from table2
inner join table1  on table1.id = table2.id
where ?table1.id=table2.id and...?
```

No idea how to modify the sql statement such that it will only update `dt` to the largest corresponding `dt2` which is not greater than the current date.

Hope it isn't too confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either using group and aggregates by in your derived table there, or possibly look into cross apply.  Here's an example of the former.

```
update table1 
set table1.dt = table2.dt2 
from table1 join (
       select id,max(dt2) as maxDT
       from table2
       group by id) as derivedTable2 on derivedTable2 .id = table1.id
```

Comment: Sorry.  Also with regards to not greater than the current date, you could just add that in a having clause.

Comment: try using the having clause but it does not work, the where clause works though. i have marked it as the answer although it needs to have the where clause in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     [dbo].[Table1].dt = [dbo].[Table2].dt2
FROM    [dbo].[Table2]
where [dbo].[Table2].id = [dbo].[Table1].id and [dbo].[Table2].dt2 > [dbo].[Table1].dt 
and [dbo].[Table2].dt2 <= getdate()
```

If i'm correcting in what you're trying to achieve you are after the "where" statement that says: where id's are equal and date in Table2 is greater that what you already have in table1 and the date in table2 is less than today? then update.

Comment: generally it works, but it does not update to the max possible datetime in one go. i need to update to the max possible datetime in one run.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this construct would work:

```
UPDATE  table1
SET     dt = dt2
FROM    ( SELECT    id AS _id ,
                    MAX(dt2) AS dt2
          FROM      ( SELECT    T2.id ,
                                T2.dt2
                      FROM      Table1 T1
                                INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
                      WHERE     T2.dt2 < T1.dt
                    ) A
          GROUP BY  id
        ) B
WHERE   id = _id;
```